External power for 3,5" HDD with USB-C charger
I'm trying to use one of my 2 HDDs (requiring 0,75A and less on both 5V and 12V) as external drive for storage. I tried using UGREEN Sata to USB-C adapter, but it has not enough power.
I know, that 3,5" drives require both 5V and 12V to operate. Some better quality charger with USB-C ports include the 12V as supported. Would such a charger be a good pick, to power the drive?
I was thinking about:
Charger > USB-C - power cable for drives > HDD + additional SATA to USB-C for data exchange.
How wrong am I with this?

Your dock or adaptor would need to support USB PD - and USB C does not necessarily mean power delivery support.
Generally I've gotten 3.5 inch drives working either on docks with dedicated power supplies, or  those cheap minimal ones with a separate barrel jack - which could take a USB C trigger cable. In theory if you had a connector that just did data and you ran power separately  it would work. I guess the 'problem' is that I've never seen anything with the combination of features you've seen, breaking out power and data seperately.

Charger > USB-C - power cable for drives > HDD + additional SATA to USB-C for data exchange.

Basically this doesn't exist as far as I know and at some point it makes a lot more sense to just get a 'toaster' style dock than having a mess of cables and a bare hard drive sitting around. While you have the same 2 power and data cables, things are a lot neater.

I wouldn't be concerned about the adapter, as if you dig, there are pretty solid options with good PD. I have checked, and there are not really any adapter sata III to usb, so it kinda kills the idea. It may sound like more mess, but I didn't want to get the whole station, because I usually have the charger with me, so it would be just carring the 2 cable adapters. I think I will stick with standard barrel adapter. Thanks!
